# Assigning an id to a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to assign an ID into a pattern so that someone could write something in my first text field, and then write a key word in the second textfield, then the key word will be the pattern searched by the RegExp.

JavaScript

```
function getInput(textfield)
{   // get value from field
    var inString = document.getElementById("string").value;
    var inSubstring = document.getElementById("substring").value;

    // search for pattern
    var patt1 = /Id/g;

    // document.writeln(patt1);

    var result = inString.match(patt1); 

    // choose paragraph and write the result
    document.writeln(result);

    // document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = result;

}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <label>Enter a string
        <input id="string" name="string" type="text" />
        </label>
        <input name="Button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="Button" onclick="getInput('textfield')" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Enter a substring to search
        <input id="substring" name="substring" type="text" />
      </label>
    </form>

    <p id="Answer">  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object instead of an inline regex :

```
function getInput(textfield)
{   // get value from field
    var inString = document.getElementById("string").value;
    var inSubstring = document.getElementById("substring").value;

    // search for pattern
    var patt1 = new RegExp(inSubstring, "g");

    // document.writeln(patt1);

    var result = inString.match(patt1); 

    // choose paragraph and write the result
    document.writeln(result);

    // document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this regex to change:

```
var patt1 = /Id/g;
```

And support a variable id to be searched.

You can use `RegExp` object with word boundaries:

```
var patt1 = new RegExp('\\b' + id + '\\b', 'g');
```

OR else you can just dump the regex and use `String#indexOf` like this:

```
index = inString.indexOf(id);
```

Comment: You're welcome. I believe word boundaries are pretty important for you.